# How to make a child theme independent of parent?

Tags: child-theme

I recently made a twentyten child theme, but I'm curious as to how I can make the child theme independent of its parent, ie exist without the twenty-ten theme folder present.

I couldn't find any information on this and thought WP answers could shed some light.

Comment: clone twentyten, rename first line in `styles.css`, rename folder. cherish it as your own forever and ever.

Answer (score 1):

An independent theme is not a child theme anymore.

Copy the original theme instead, use another name and another directory name too.
Do not use the `Template: othertheme` part in your `style.css` headers.

That’s all. No magic. :)